# Problema con bucles perfectamente anidados

Tags: c, bucle-for

tengo un problema ya que en un programa de c que es wa-tor(peces y tiburones) a la hora de hacer un collapse(2) para mejorar mediciones de tiempos me dice que los bucles no estan perfectamente anidados, es sobre OMP. Me gustaria saber como podria poner estos bucles perfectamente anidados.

Tambien me ayudaria saber la diferencia entre un bucle perfectamente anidado y otro que no lo está, cualquier ejemplo es de ayuda.
Dejo la parte del programa y una captura de la consola.
Muchas gracias.

*Remarco con <<<< las 3 partes de los bucles y el collapse (2)*

[Imagen por consola]
[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu3AQ.png][1]][1]

```
<<<<<        //First loop 
        #ifdef _OPENMP
         #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(Rows, Cols, Ocean, SimIter, pNFishes, NiFBreed, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes, local_N_Sharks) collapse(2)
        #endif
         for (int i=0; i<Rows; i = i + 3) {
             // loop 1.1
             for (int j=0; j<Cols; j = j + 3)
                 {
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==FISH)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                     IterateFish(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter,pNFishes,NiFBreed, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes);
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==SHARK)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                 IterateShark(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter, pNFishes, pNSharks, NiSBreed, SiEnergy, SeFEnergy, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes, local_N_Sharks);
        
                 }
              // Loop 1.2
              for (int j=1; j<Cols; j = j + 3)
                 {
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==FISH)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                     IterateFish(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter,pNFishes,NiFBreed, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes);
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==SHARK)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                 IterateShark(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter, pNFishes, pNSharks, NiSBreed, SiEnergy, SeFEnergy, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes, local_N_Sharks);
        
                 }
               //Loop 1.3
               for (int j=2; j<Cols; j = j + 3)
                 {
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==FISH)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                     IterateFish(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter,pNFishes,NiFBreed, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes);
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==SHARK)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                 IterateShark(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter, pNFishes, pNSharks, NiSBreed, SiEnergy, SeFEnergy, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes, local_N_Sharks);
        
                 }
                
             } //End first loop
        
   <<<<<      //Second loop
         #ifdef _OPENMP
          #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(Rows, Cols, Ocean, SimIter, pNFishes, NiFBreed, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes, local_N_Sharks) collapse(2)
        #endif
         for (int i=1; i<Rows; i = i + 3) {
             // loop 2.1
             for (int j=0; j<Cols; j = j + 3)
                 {
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==FISH)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                     IterateFish(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter,pNFishes,NiFBreed, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes);
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==SHARK)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                 IterateShark(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter, pNFishes, pNSharks, NiSBreed, SiEnergy, SeFEnergy, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes, local_N_Sharks);
        
                 }
              // Loop 2.2
              for (int j=1; j<Cols; j = j + 3)
                 {
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==FISH)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                     IterateFish(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter,pNFishes,NiFBreed, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes);
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==SHARK)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                 IterateShark(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter, pNFishes, pNSharks, NiSBreed, SiEnergy, SeFEnergy, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes, local_N_Sharks);
        
                 }
               //Loop 2.3
               for (int j=2; j<Cols; j = j + 3)
                 {
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==FISH)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                     IterateFish(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter,pNFishes,NiFBreed, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes);
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==SHARK)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                 IterateShark(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter, pNFishes, pNSharks, NiSBreed, SiEnergy, SeFEnergy, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes, local_N_Sharks);
        
                 }
        
             } //End second loop
        
 <<<<<<        //Third loop
        #ifdef _OPENMP
          #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(Rows, Cols, Ocean, SimIter, pNFishes, NiFBreed, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes, local_N_Sharks) collapse(2)
        #endif
         for (int i=2; i<Rows; i = i + 3) {
             // loop 3.1
             for (int j=0; j<Cols; j = j + 3)
                 {
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==FISH)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                     IterateFish(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter,pNFishes,NiFBreed, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes);
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==SHARK)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                 IterateShark(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter, pNFishes, pNSharks, NiSBreed, SiEnergy, SeFEnergy, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes, local_N_Sharks);
        
                 }
              // Loop 3.2
              for (int j=1; j<Cols; j = j + 3)
                 {
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==FISH)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                     IterateFish(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter,pNFishes,NiFBreed, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes);
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==SHARK)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                 IterateShark(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter, pNFishes, pNSharks, NiSBreed, SiEnergy, SeFEnergy, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes, local_N_Sharks);
        
                 }
               //Loop 3.3
               for (int j=2; j<Cols; j = j + 3)
                 {
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==FISH)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                     IterateFish(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter,pNFishes,NiFBreed, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes);
                  if (Ocean[i][j]!=NULL && Ocean[i][j]->Animal==SHARK)
                     //TODO Add pRandData and pRandRes parameters at the end
                     IterateShark(Ocean,Rows,Cols,i,j,SimIter, pNFishes, pNSharks, NiSBreed, SiEnergy, SeFEnergy, pRandData, pRandRes, local_N_Fishes, local_N_Sharks);
                 }
        
             } //End third loop
```